# Vista permission denied for command line utility running in Program Files

Tags: permissions, windows-vista

I'm trying to add a tool to Visual Studio and it is a DOS command line utility.

The command line args require a path to a config file. It seems that no matter where I try to store this config file, the command line utility can not get permission to open the file.

I tried

```
C:\ProgramData\Utilities\JavascriptLint\
C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Utilities\JavaScriptLint\
C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Roaming\Utilities\JavaScriptLint\
```

I tried the program folder. I tried to set security to allow everyone access, but still not good.

I read about the symbolic links and junctions problems so I use `CMD dir /Al` to find the real folders. I'm tearing what little hair I have left trying to make this simple command utility work in Visual Studio. It shouldn't be this hard!

Comment: Did you started the shell as administrator? If not try that.

Comment: No, but why would a command line utility need to be run as administrator just so it can READ its configuration file?

I got the command line utility to run by not trying to execute it in the c:\Program Files(86)\ folder space. This must require some kind of admin privs that Visual Studio can't provide.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. Put your solution in a answer, you can then accept it as correct after 2 days. This way your questions will show up as solved when other people are browsing SO.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a comment. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I got the command line utility to run by not trying to execute it in the `:\Program Files(86)\` folder space. This must require some kind of admin privs that Visual Studio can't provide.